# c# winform drawn image flashing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a image drawn in an winform app and i designed a brush that moves after the cursor. The Brush is drawn every time so the image keeps flashing because the image is also redrawn . How can i avoid this ?

Regards,
Alex Badescu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the form's `DoubleBuffered` property to true. That should solve the flickering.

No reason to make it more advanced than this, in such a simple scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Use double-buffering. Draw each frame to some kind of memory bitmap representing the back buffer and once it's drawn show it on the first.

For more info read here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457.aspx

Comment: it kind of wasn't enough .. it still flickered . i introduced the following code

Comment: SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);